# Windows Azure Issue - First request fails but second succeeds?

Tags: asp.net, azure, hosting

For the last 10 hours my website has been partially down due to being hosted in the West Europe region (an issue from the servers of Windows Azure).
Now they state that the servers are perfectly up and running again:
www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

However my issue is that when I send a get request to my site I get a server error. But when I submit the same request quickly afterwards it loads just fine.
Anyone knows what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL will close connection after a period of idle time, make sure you add retry machanism so when first connect to SQL failed, you try one more time.